# Why does connected react-redux component not work as normal function, but does as a react child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to create an external functional component, which doesnt need to return any JSX, but just needs to send some internal React state to the Redux store. To keep my `App.js` clean i was trying to do this in an external file. For some reason the code below, where `ChromeStoreToReduxStore` is rendered as a child component, does not raise an error.

ChromeStoreToReduxStore.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../popupRedux/actions'

function ChromeStoreToReduxStore (props) {
  console.log(props)

  return null
}

export default connect(null, actions)(ChromeStoreToReduxStore);
```

App.js

```
function App (props) {

  //state to keep track of local chrome store
  const [chromeStore, updateChromeStore] = useState({})

  ...
  console.log(ChromeStoreToReduxStore)

 ...
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChromeStoreToReduxStore chromeStore = {chromeStore} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

However, calling the component in `App.js` like below gives the following error: `TypeError: ChromeStoreToReduxStore is not a function`

```
//whenever local store state changes send to redux store
  useEffect(() => {
    ChromeStoreToReduxStore(chromeStore);
  }, [chromeStore])
```

The `console.log` below shows it appears to be a react memo. **Can anyone explain why i cant call this function wrapped in `connect` like a normal function, and why it seems to have to be rendered as a React child?**

I know i could just connect to the store inside `App.js` but would like to know why the above does not work.

[image]

Comment: connect function from react-redux is a HOC which wraps your function in a class component to provide extra functionality, which makes it no longer a function but a class.

Comment: @JacobSmit ah ok. So i guess that means it will just have to be placed in my return statement and rendered like any other class component?

Comment: Or make a hook, then add the hook to a component and have both, a hook to call from any function component, or a ChromeToReduxStore component that you can add to any render

Comment: what do you mean by add a hook? How would i call a react hook from another component? Could you possibly give a very simple example of how i could do this?

Comment: This is a really rough example of what I was attempting to say: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-h53s7z?file=index.tsx](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-h53s7z?file=index.tsx)

Comment: Updated the example to add a comment about how to use redux actions via a hook, avoiding the need for using `connect()`